# Is it possible to reuse parts of AndroidManifest.xml files?

Tags: android, android-manifest, dry

A lot of configurations go into `AndroidManifest.xml` file. For many applications some of those configurations are the same. For example this provider that is required to access file providers for android versions upper than 7:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/paths"/>
</provider>
```

This is not application specific. It's desired to have this fragment of XML somewhere, and reuse it across many applications.

I can't find anything related to reusing XML fragments across many AndroidManifest.xml files. Can we do that?

**Update**: This question is not about [Android Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments). I'm talking about XML code blocks. I'm trying to apply DRY (do not repeat yourself) principle to `AndroidManifest.xml` files across many projects.

Comment: Manfest is Application related and activities .. resuing fragments should be code in layout xml.. not manifest..

Comment: I am not getting your question properly. By Fragment what do you want to say? Are you talking about actual fragment concept or just referring some `XML code block` (e.g. provider code block) as a fragment?

Comment: @ItzikSamara @ JaydipKalkani  by "fragment", he means "part". Not the fragment in Android's context.

Comment: @JaydipKalkani, I'm talking about some XML code block. I mean reusing code snippets that are duplicate in AndroidManifest.xml. I'm talking about DRY (do not repeat yourself) for AndroidManifest files across many projects.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no such way for not repeating xml code blocks. There is a concept that let's make you free from writing same code multiple times. Android studio will do it by itself. you just need to write a small keyword. The concept is called `Live Templates` in android studio.

For creating template, go to **File -> Settings -> Editor -> Live Templates**. Then click `+` button located at right side and select `Live Template`. In Abbreviation put shortcut keyword (e.g. provider) and put your code in `Template Text` and also define `XML` as a template context. **It's Important to define context!**. That's all!

Now whenever you want to use the same code you can write Abbreviation (e.g. provider) in your XML file and your whole `Template Text` code will be pasted there.

Comment: Nice tip. May be i will use it for other code snippets too.

Comment: This is way off the answer I was looking for. I'm not a man of downvoting, but this truly deserves a downvote. Instead of defining templates, I could simply have a simple text files saved somewhere to be used as the source of copy/paste. When we insist DRY, we're not talking about laziness for not writing things. We're talking about the quality it brings in maintenance.